# How can i add attribute name and Column value from an xml file to Dictionary

Tags: python

```
<table name="table1">
    <col>Comp1</col>
    <col>Compo4_</col>
    <col>Dire3</col>
    <col>Attri4s</col>
    <col>Condition</col>
    </table>

<table name="table2">
    <col>Compo4_</col>
    <col>Compon7</col>
    <col>Direc9</col>
    </table>
```

i have an xml file as given above.i want to add the value of tablename and the col no of Compo4_ to a dictionary.i tried the following code.But every time iam getting the first column value in coltext.

```
    dic={}
    for node in doc.getElementsByTagName('table'):
        name = node.getAttribute('name')
        value=0
        for subnode in node.childNodes:
            if subnode.nodeType == node.ELEMENT_NODE and subnode.tagName == "col":
                colvalue=colvalue+1
                coltext = subnode.getElementsByTagName('col')
                if coltext=='Compo4_':
                    componentIddic[table_name]=colvalue
```

Please don't suggest me to use Elementree.Because our whole implemenatation we are using minidom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coltext seems to be different from what you're expecting. Try to use the firstChild attribute.

```
coltext = subnode.firstChild.nodeValue
```

My result is

```
{'table2': 6, 'table1': 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [xmltodict](http://www.myildirim.net/xml-parsing-python-xmltodict/) module simply, with xmltodict you don't need to convert xml to dict manually. xmltodict provideds it for yourself automatically.

```
>>> import xmltodict    
>>> s = xmltodict.parse('<table name="table1">
    <col>Comp1</col>
    <col>Compon4_</col>
    <col>Dire3</col>
    <col>Attri4s</col>
    <col>Condition</col>
    </table>')

>>>for i in s:
        print s['table']['col']
>>>[u'Comp1', u'Compon4_', u'Dire3', u'Attri4s', u'Condition']
```

Comment: we are using python python2.6 can't use this xmltodict